# Excel uniqe value count in cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to count a unique value after a decimal point in a cell?

2,3,4,5,6 = 5 ? in one cell

I am trying to make each number identified as 1 and summed

Comment: it is not apparent what you are asking,  please use a mark down table to show each value in each cell and expected output.  You say Unique after decimal.  I do not see any decimal.  I also do not see non unique.  please include enough examples to show your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Assume you have the data in cell `A1`, then:

```
=COLUMNS(TEXTSPLIT(A1, ",")
```

or

```
=ROWS(TEXTSPLIT(A1,, ","))
```

If you mean by "unique", unique numbers then you need to wrap the `TEXTSPLIT` output with the `UNIQUE` function.